# url rewrite on godaddy dynamic php pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a url rewrite for php dynamic pages.  The rewrite sends them to the page but I am getting a 404 error.   In my php page i use $coinshow =$_REQUEST['coinshow'];

I want to to go from sitename.com/coinShowPage.php?coinshow=XyzShow to sitename.com/XyzShow  or I would be happy with sitename.com/coinshows/XyzShow too.

Please note coinShowPage.php is the only page I need redirected.

Here is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Za-z]{3,}\s/+coinShowPage\.php\?coinshow=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.SiteName.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

I already tried the following and it did not work

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?$ coinShowPage.php?coinshow=$1 [NC,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Za-z]{3,}\s/+coinShowPage\.php\?coinshow=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.SiteName.com/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ coinShowPage.php?coinshow=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What sample url are you getting redirected to?

Comment: the link is coming out correct ...  
mysite.com/northwestbestshow  but the 404 error page is being displayed.  It seems like the page is not grabbing the variable  that is supposed to be passed.  coinShowPage.php requests the variable like:  $id = $_REQUEST['coinshow'];

Comment: Check update. Your original rule suggested that coinshow would be numeric which is why it didn't match northwest... I've updated the rule to match on all values now. Just make sure you never have a dir/file with the same name as coinshow parameter in your root directory.

Comment: How would I change  sitename.com/search.php to sitename.com/search